# How to clone a virtualbox guest in link mode along with its saved state?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm looking for a way to quickly clone a VirtualBox guest, start it, use for a while, and toss it away. Therefore I think it's best to use link mode so that there is no need to copy the whole vdi file. It will also be nice to clone the saved state as well so that the new cloned guest can be started in a few seconds without the boot process. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at VBoxManage.  It has commands like clonevm, startvm, 'snapshot take...', and
controlvm that should let you put together a script that does what you want.

- Eric